# Written out 1000 integers. Prove that they can be painted in two colors so that the ratio of numbers of the same color is not a prime.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Written out 1000 integers.  Prove that they can be painted in two colors so that the ratio of numbers of the same color is not a prime.

I tried to make a 2 part complate graph , but I dont know what to do

Comment: I think you should put a restriction on painting. Otherwise, just paint 800 into red and 200 into blue so that the ratio is 4.

Comment: What does "ratio of numbers of the same colour" exactly mean? Do the *values* of these painted integers somehow count? Or could they just be any small dots that are coloured?

Comment: Oh, $\frac{x_i}{x_j}$ is not a prime if $x_i$, $x_j$ painted with the same color.

Comment: What if $\frac{x_i}{x_j}$ is not an integer ? When you say the ratio is "not a prime" do you mean that  $x_i$ and $x_j$ must be co-prime if they are the same colour ? But then what if all $1000$ integers are multiples of $2$ (or have some other prime factor in common) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paint by reminder modulo $2$ of sum of exponents $\sum\limits_{i}{\alpha_i}$ of prime factorization $\prod\limits_{i}p_i^{\alpha_i}$.